# how to run two version of odoo simultaneously using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, odoo-9, odoo-10

I need help regarding odoo.
How to run two different version of odoo run simultaneously using eclipse.
Both odoo version work on different port.

Comment: Good question, I have odoo 9 and eclipse on port 8069, I want add odoo 10 version on my ubuntu.

Comment: you add the odoo 9 same as add odoo 10 and create both have separate configuration file for run program and both for take different port number because you run at same time both odoo version on browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a configuration file for both projects like the following in `odoo_server.conf` file. With different port numbers.

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5433
db_user = openerp
db_password = openerp
addons_path = F:\Francis\Workspace\studica\addons
xmlrpc_port=7070
pg_path = E:\santhosh\upsynth_Postgres\bin
```

then create **Run configuration** in Eclipse for both projects
[image]

Then add the configuration file path in the **Arguments tab** for both projects.
[image]

Now you will be able to Run 2 projects with different source code at the same time.

You can see the Logs for both like the following

[image]

Same procedure for both Windows and Linux version of Eclipse